# Why is an answer shown in First posts review queue when I filtered it for only questions?

Tags: bug, review-queue, first-posts

I was in the First posts review queue reviewing posts. I noticed this suddenly:

[image: Screenshot of the First posts review queue: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1163303]

Link: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1163303

As you can see in the screenshot, I have used the filter option to only see questions. But I was asked to review an answer.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this happened because that was not a real review but a review audit.

[image: review audit passed]

I guess filters don't work on review audits for some reason. Generally review audits are pretty shoddy.

Sorry!

Comment: Please don't be sorry. It ain't your mistake. SE needs to fix this. I think I need to post about this in MSE.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368658